# VBA open file in active worksheet

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a code to open an Excel file (CSV file actually) in the active worksheet of a workbook. The file is not always located on the same location and does not always have the same name. Therefore I want the user to be able to browse the file.

I tried the code shown below. The code works partially, the code now opens the file in a new workbook. However, I would like to open the file/get the data in the active worksheet. Do you know how I could change the code to do this?

```
    Sub OpenFile()
    Dim FileName As String, test As Workbook
    On Error GoTo ErrorMessage

    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for workbook")

    'Open workbook
    Workbooks.Open FileName
    Set test = ActiveWorkbook
    Exit Sub

    ErrorMessage:
    MsgBox ("Je hebt geen bestand geselecteerd, probeer het nogmaals.")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Try recording a macro while using the data/text import wizard. You want to import data, not open a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the workbook the user selects and copy whatever sheet you need into your current workbook. Edit: This will paste it into your active sheet using UsedRange as others have shown.

```
Sub OpenFile()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim FileName As String, test As Workbook
    Dim shActive As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrorMessage

    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for workbook")

    'Open workbook
    Set shActive = ActiveSheet
    Set test = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

    'copy the sheet you need from that workbook into your current workbook
    test.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy shActive.Range("A1")

    'close the previous workbook
    test.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Exit Sub

ErrorMessage:
    MsgBox ("Je hebt geen bestand geselecteerd, probeer het nogmaals.")

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! Very helpful! Just one more question: I would like it to open the file in the active worksheet, and not in a new worksheet. Do you know if that's possible as well?

Comment: Yes, the edit will paste into the ActiveSheet instead of a new sheet, similar to what TinMan has shown.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I need! Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the file copy the cells to the target worksheet.

```
Sub OpenFile()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Comma Separated Values,*.csv", , "Browse for workbook")

    If FileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy TargetWorksheet.Range("A1")
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the help! Both options (the one edited by TheJeebo) seem to work! Very helpfull!